# iOS - Archiving "bitcode bundle" could not be generated - Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, bitcode, razorpay

I am facing this issue and unable to release the app in Appstore. App is already in App Store and i want to release a new version now. This issue is in my latest build . I am able to build the product and its also running properly on iOS devices.
When i select product==> archive then its showing as build failed.

error ==>

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
> '/Users/XXX/XXX/XXX/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter' was built
> without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be
> generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file
> '/Users/XXX/XXX/XXX/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter' for
> architecture armv7

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

pubspec.yaml ==> **razorpay_flutter: ^1.1.3**

xcode version ==> **Version 11.2.1**

In my podfile.lock ==>

> razorpay-pod (1.1.5)
>
> razorpay_flutter (1.1.5): Flutter razorpay-pod

In my pod file ==>

> platform :ios, '10.0' use_frameworks!

> config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'

> config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5.2'

Please help.

Thanks,
Shruti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing below 2 steps in Xcode solved this issue.

1. Runner -> ['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
2. File -> workspace settings --> Build system --> set -->legacy build system.

Comment: how does it can be modified ['ENABLE_BITCODE'] in Runner file flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `ENABLE_BITCODE` resolved this.

The following should be part of the `Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```